# for loop with index xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to have a table with 3 column, based on 2 nodes of an xml file, like this http://jsfiddle.net/4n36W/

**XML**

```
<Root>
  <Items>
    <a>10</a>
    <b>20</b>
    <c>30</c>
  </Items>
  <Errors>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>3</c>
  </Errors>
</Root>
```

My xsl file looks like this, from what I've found in some post of stackoverflow. With this file I have the following error:

> ```
> XPTY0020: Required item type of the context item for the child axis is node(); supplied
>   value has item type xs:integer
> ```

**XSL**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column A</th>
            <th>Column B</th>
            <th>Column C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to 3">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!-- <xsl:value-of select="Root/Items/local-name()" /> -->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="(Root/Items/*)[position()=$pos]" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="(Root/Errors/*)[position()=$pos]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this differently, by iterating over the `Items/*` elements and extracting the matching `Errors` child by position:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Root/Items/*">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../Errors/*[$pos]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I thought iterating over an index would be better, but thank you, it works. Anyway, is it possible to do this with index?

Comment: @thibon you can `for-each` over a sequence of numbers instead of a sequence of nodes, but you'll need to preserve the outer context in a `<xsl:variable name="dot" select="."/>` before you enter the `for-each` and then select nodes via `$dot/Items[$pos]` (or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are having a for-each with select="1 to 3". Thus, the context node is an atomic value.

One of the options is to save your root node in variable and use it inside for-each:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="Root" select="Root"/>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column A</th>
                <th>Column B</th>
                <th>Column C</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="1 to 3">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- <xsl:value-of select="Root/Items/local-name()" /> -->
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Root/Items/*[position() = $pos]" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Root/Errors/*[position()=$pos]" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```